# See the file name and size within a (.Z) compressed file without uncompressing it

Tags: compression

I have tons of .Z compressed files scattered across various directores and need to see the size of the file within it. I don't plan on uncompressing all the .Z files. Is there a way to see the content (typically 1 file) the size of? I am aware of only zcat, which only cats the file.
Thanks!
Steve

Comment: Can you run `file oneofyourfiles.Z` and tell us the exact string you get from that? (I'm a bit worried about the "typically" single file)

Comment: Yes it is just 1 file in a .Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The utility `uncompress` do not have the option to list the archive (and uncompressed size) like `gzip`. But you can decompress in memory and count the bytes of decompressed file like this:

```
uncompress -c archive.Z|wc -c
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much! It worked....  So I assume this works under AIX or Linux and all flavours of the OS, since "Uncompress" must be standard with that switch (flag) across the board?

Comment: @Steve237, I do not have AIX or HP-UX but it work under Solaris 11 (x86) and RHEL. And you are right, as `uncomporess` is available there it should work :)